# change request base url in gwt rpc call

Tags: java, gwt, request, rpc

We have a gwt application hosted on one server with the domain (ex. xyz.com)
Now we are developing the mobile version for the same gwt application and our mobile version is also developing in gwt only.

The mobile version will be hosted on subdomain (ex. m.xyz.com)

Now we want keep the server side code for both the application common. We want that the mobile application must generate the rpc request for main application only (i.e. xyz.com).

**So how can we change the base url of the rpc request in gwt.**

Comment: without a hack, it will not work. Think about the same origin policy ...

Comment: @ElHoss  unless they setup CORS on the server...